# How to stop icc from eliminating function called from inline assembly

Tags: c, optimization, icc

## Background

I'm making an app that needs to run several tasks concurrently. I can't use threads and such because the app should work without any OS (i.e. straight from the bootsector). Using x86 tasks looks like an overkill (both logically and performance-wise). Thus, I decided to implement a task-switching utility myself. I would save processor state, make a call to the task code and then restore the previous state. So I have to make the call from inline assembly.

## Problem

Here's some example code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void func() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}

void (*funcptr)();

int main() {
    funcptr = func;
    asm(
        "call *%0;"
        :
        :"r"(funcptr)
    );
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles perfectly under icc with no options, gcc and clang and yields "Hello, world!" when run. However, if I compile it with `icc main.c -ipo`, it segfaults.

I disassembled the code that was generated by `icc main.c` and got the following:

```
0000000000401220 <main>:
  401220:   55                      push   %rbp
  401221:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  401224:   48 83 e4 80             and    $0xffffffffffffff80,%rsp
  401228:   48 81 ec 80 00 00 00    sub    $0x80,%rsp
  40122f:   bf 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%edi
  401234:   33 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
  401236:   e8 45 00 00 00          callq  401280 <__intel_new_feature_proc_init>
  40123b:   0f ae 1c 24             stmxcsr (%rsp)
  40123f:   48 c7 05 f6 78 00 00    movq   $0x401270,0x78f6(%rip)        # 408b40 <funcptr>
  401246:   70 12 40 00 
  40124a:   b8 70 12 40 00          mov    $0x401270,%eax
  40124f:   81 0c 24 40 80 00 00    orl    $0x8040,(%rsp)
  401256:   0f ae 14 24             ldmxcsr (%rsp)
  40125a:   ff d0                   callq  *%rax
  40125c:   33 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40125e:   48 89 ec                mov    %rbp,%rsp
  401261:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  401262:   c3                      retq   
  401263:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  401268:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40126f:   00 

0000000000401270 <func>:
  401270:   bf 04 40 40 00          mov    $0x404004,%edi
  401275:   e9 e6 fd ff ff          jmpq   401060 <puts@plt>
  40127a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

On the other hand, `icc main.c -ipo` yields:

```
0000000000401210 <main>:
  401210:   55                      push   %rbp
  401211:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  401214:   48 83 e4 80             and    $0xffffffffffffff80,%rsp
  401218:   48 81 ec 80 00 00 00    sub    $0x80,%rsp
  40121f:   bf 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%edi
  401224:   33 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
  401226:   e8 25 00 00 00          callq  401250 <__intel_new_feature_proc_init>
  40122b:   0f ae 1c 24             stmxcsr (%rsp)
  40122f:   81 0c 24 40 80 00 00    orl    $0x8040,(%rsp)
  401236:   48 8b 05 cb 2d 00 00    mov    0x2dcb(%rip),%rax        # 404008 <funcptr_2.dp.0>
  40123d:   0f ae 14 24             ldmxcsr (%rsp)
  401241:   ff d0                   callq  *%rax
  401243:   33 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  401245:   48 89 ec                mov    %rbp,%rsp
  401248:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  401249:   c3                      retq   
  40124a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

So, while `-ipo` didn't remove `funcptr` variable (see address 401236), it *did* remove assignment. I guess that icc noticed that `func` is not called from C code so it can be safely removed, so `funcptr` is allowed to contain garbage. However, it didn't notice that I'm calling `func` indirectly via assembly.

## What I tried

1. Replacing `"r"(funcptr)` with `"r"(func)` works but I can't hardcode a specific function (see background).
2. Calling `funcptr` and/or `func` before and/or after inline assembly block don't help because icc just inlines `printf("Hello, world!\n");`.
3. I can't get rid of inline assembly because I have to do low-level register, flags and stack manipulation before and after call.
4. Making funcptr volatile yields the following warning but still segfaults:

```
a value of type "void (*)()" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "volatile void (*)()"
```

5. Adding `volatile` to almost every other word doesn't help either.
6. Moving `func` and/or `funcptr` to other source files and then linking them together doesn't help.
7. Moving inline assembly to a separate function doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong or is it an icc bug? If the former, how do I fix the code? If the latter, is there any workaround and should I report the bug?

```
$ icc --version
icc (ICC) 19.1.0.166 20191121
Copyright (C) 1985-2019 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Comment: That does seem like a bug to me.  Does it help if you declare `funcptr` as `volatile`?

Comment: On the other hand, what version of icc is this, and what other options are you using?  I tried it on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Qnydiy) and can't reproduce.

Comment: I've updated the question. volatile doesn't help. I'm compiling with `icc main.c -ipo` and running with `./a.out`.

Comment: Perhaps you could see if you can reproduce it on godbolt, and post the link, so that those of us who don't have icc installed can test.

Comment: It sounds like you wrote `volatile void (*funcptr)(void);` but what I meant was `void (* volatile funcptr)(void);`.

Comment: You are right, sorry. Using `volatile *funcptr` gives `warning #945: type qualifier ignored`. Both it and `*volatile funcptr` segfault.

Comment: Same with `*volatile funcptr`. I think that icc just thinks it's more clever than the programmer and ignores it.

Comment: Inline assembly is an extension to C, so any answer must be based on the details of (some version of) `icc` -- garnered either from experience or from that compiler's documentation.  Or you could just avoid using the `-ipo` option when compiling with `icc`.  Do you have a way to estimate or test how much advantage `-ipo` actually stands to offer?

Comment: I have rather many cross-file calls so I thought `-ipo` might help. Unfortunately, I can't estimate the advantage because the scheduler itself (the part that does task switching) doesn't work with `-ipo`. I was actually trying `-ipo` to measure if it would make any performance-wise difference.

Comment: Does it help if you place caller and callee in different translation units (vulgo: modules)?

Comment: No, nothing changes.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the asm in a static inline function with a function pointer parameter?

Comment: Same, it segfaults.

Comment: Per my godbolt link above, it looks like the problem occurs on a later pass than compilation.  The assembly output from the compiler looks okay, but if you build the binary and then disassemble (the "11010" button) you see the offending code.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a linker problem then. Do you think it's a bug I should report?

Comment: I think it's worth reporting, yes.  It appeared in my tests that `funcptr` is statically initialized to something that looks like a function address, but there is garbage at that address.  So it may be that `funcptr` is correctly set to the address of `func`, but then the code for `func` itself is dropped later because Intel's linker thinks it isn't used.

Comment: I found you can work around it by writing a no-op function in a separate source file which you compile with gcc instead of icc, and calling this function with `funcptr` as an argument.  This basically defeats the ipo because icc doesn't know anything about code compiled by gcc.  But it seems too much of an unreliable hack to be appropriate for production.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but could this be related to `-Wl,--gc-sections`? Have you tried passing `-Wl,--no-gc-sections` to disable the elemination of dead code? Maybe you have set `-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections`?